# put a break tag between two variables

Tags: php, syntax

how do you put a break tag between two variables that are being joined together.

```
 $streetAdress  = "{$address->getHouseNumber()} {$address->getStreet()}<br/>, {$address->getCity()}";
```

in the example above i tried just putting the line break within the "" but when i then tried to render the $streeAddress variable in a Texterarra the break tags showed up

```
<textarea cols=30 name=address rows=4>
     <?php echo $streetAdress ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: try `\n` instead of `<br/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanna use `\n` instead of `<br>`.